# how to get the items in listbox one by one in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listboxitem

how to get the items in listbox one by one

e.g : in my listbox i have items (roll no's)

s1
s2
s3
s4
s5
etc...

how to get the items on by one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to pick out specific items you can do following (nul-based) :

```
string item = lstItems.Items[index].toString();
```

if you need all items in a list, you can use David's method, or much shorter, use this

```
var myList = lbMyListBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 IList<string> items = new List<string>();

 foreach(ListItem item in myListBox.Items)
 {
     items.Add(item.Text);
 }
```